# What the heck does 'ALFKI' mean?

Tags: sql-server, web-services

I've seen this abbreviation (or mnemonic) used in various examples in SQL and web services.

What does it mean? And if you know, what are its origins?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It's the primary key (CustomerID)  of the First `Customer` entry in the Microsoft Northwind Demo Database

```
ALFKI   
Alfreds Futterkiste 
Maria Anders    
Sales Representative    
Obere Str. 57   Berlin      
12209   
Germany 
030-0074321 
030-0076545
```

Comment: Ha!  I thought I was missing something, reviewing code and thought I was losing it.

Comment: ALFKI has meme potential. It could be the new 'foo' or 'bar'.

Answer (score 16):

It's the unique key of "Alfreds Futterkiste", the first "Customers" table entry in Microsoft's "Northwind" sample database that ships with SQL Server.

Answer (score 13):

'ALFKI' is the primary identifier of a known Customer record in the Northwind sample Database from Microsoft.

It is used here and there almost as "foobar" is used as a canonical variable name.

Answer (score 5):

It's a sample customer in `Microsoft` supplied `Northwind` database (used for tests)

Answer (score 4):

Customer key from the Northwind sample database that Microsoft used over the years.